# How to filter a JSON in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I have the following JSON stored in a variable named data. How can i filter it excluding the "0" values?

```
{
  "BTC": "0",
  "XCP": "0",
  "LTC": "0",
  "NXT": "0",
  "XPM": "0",
  "NMC": "0",
  "MMC": "0",
  "NOBL": "0",
  "USDE": "0",
  "SOC": "0",
  "KDC": "0",
  "DOGE": "0.00000001",
  "GLB": "0",
  "Q2C": "0",
  "FOX": "0",
  "MRC": "0",
  "MTS": "0"
}
```

I tried:

```
   var datos = data.filter(function(data){
    return !!data;
    });
    res.send(data);
```

but it's telling me

> Object # has no method 'filter'

Regards,

Comment: checkout http://lodash.com/ for methods to filter straight on objects.  lodash is yet another utility library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataObj = {
  "BTC": "0",
  "XCP": "0",
  "LTC": "0",
  "NXT": "0",
  "XPM": "0",
  "NMC": "0",
  "MMC": "0",
  "NOBL": "0",
  "USDE": "0",
  "SOC": "0",
  "KDC": "0",
  "DOGE": "0.00000001",
  "GLB": "0",
  "Q2C": "0",
  "FOX": "0",
  "MRC": "0",
  "MTS": "0"
}

var keys = Object.keys(dataObj);
keys.forEach(function(key){ if(dataObj[key] === "0") delete dataObj[key];})

console.log(dataObj);
```

Comment: If you don't wish to change the original object `dataObj`, then just insert properties of interest in a new object.

Answer (score 2):

Objects dont have a filter method, you need to convert your object to an array if you want to use the array filter method.

But to answer the question,

```
var newData = {};

for(i in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(i) && data[i] != "0"){
       newData[i] = data[i];
    }
}
```